# Is there a way to do calculations when entering values in a field while using free transform in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, forms

When I enter values in free transform mode, there is a bunch of forms that indicate position of the object (x, y, etc...) I found that I can't add, subtract or multiply values in this form. It's very frustrating.

Is it impossible to do calculations in these forms? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Photoshop simply does not perform mathematical operations in transform fields.

Answer (score 1):

Scott is correct that Photoshop does not do mathematical operations inside it's transform fields. If this is something you'd like to see in Photoshop you can always make a feature request here: https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/mmform/index.cfm?name=wishform